# SWT StyledText - listen to clientArea change

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I've got problem with SWT StyledText scrollbars. I've added listeners to both (horizontal and vertical) scrollbars of my styled text:

```
styledText.getHorizontalBar().addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
    public void handleEvent (Event e) {
        //Some action
    }
});
styledText.getVerticalBar().addListener (SWT.Selection, new Listener () {
    public void handleEvent (Event e) {
        //Some action
    }
});
```

My problem is that listeners that I've added react only when user moves a scrollbar using mouse. If for example only part of the styledText is visible and user types in some text, which causes change in visible client area, than listeners are not informed about a change.

My question is - is it possible to somehow listen to changes on visible client area of the styled text?

Answer (score 4):

The JFace `TextViewer` (which uses `StyledText`) supports an `IViewportListener` which does what you want.

If you don't want to use JFace then you can duplicate how `TextViewer` calls its listener. It listens for control resize, key release, key pressed, mouse up, and widget selected. It then checks if `StyledText.getTopPixel()` has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding listeners specifically to the object returned by getHorizontalBar(), that is why nothing is happening when the user inputs text. Try adding a listener to getContent() as well. Something along the lines of:

```
styledText.getContent().addTextChangeListener (new TextChangeListener() {
            //events
        };
```

Comment: I'm interested in movement of the visible content. Your approach won't work if user for example does not type printable characters, but is pressing arrows - so in case when caret is moved to invisible part of the styled text.
But I'll be glad to hear other ideas :)

Comment: And by the way I know I can listen to caret position change, but I wanted to listen to scrollbar position change.